# Java Android Sockets Threading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, runnable

I've a client class which tries to connect to a server. But as you know you can't
execute network operations on the Main UI thread. So I've to create different threads for each operation.

Current code:

```html
package com.example.justus.rocchat;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.JsonWriter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


/**
 * Created by justus on 13-1-2015.
 */
public class Client
{

    private String name;
    private int port;
    private String hostAddress;
    private Socket socketClient;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    public boolean isConnected;

    public Client(MainActivity mainActivity, String hostAdress, int port)
    {
        this.hostAddress = hostAdress;
        this.port = port;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;

    }



   public void send(final byte[] data)
   {


           Thread sendThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run()
           {
               try
               {
                   DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());
                   out.write(data);
                   System.out.println("writed data");
               } catch (IOException ex) {
               }
           }
           });


       sendThread.start();
   }


    public void connect()
    {
        Thread connectThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("trying to connect");
            socketClient = new Socket(hostAddress, port);
            isConnected = true;

        }
        catch(UnknownHostException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ex:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ex:" + ex.getMessage());

        }
            }
        });

        connectThread.start();
    }



}
```

Isn't this a little to much? Are there any better ways to handle this operations? 
Already thanks for your time.

Comment: what makes you think this is too much ?

Comment: Creating a thread for each operation? Isn't that using to much threads then neccesary?

Comment: it depends on how your `send()` method is going to be used. you haven't specified that. you may actually end up with a single thread, if it complies with what you want to accomplish. note that the primary purpose of threading is to do some task independently i.e. asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is the accepted way of handling asynchronous operations.  It is a wrapper around the Thread class and is part of the Android SDK.  They should only be used for operations that last under a few seconds, for longer operations you should use a Service.

developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that you have

1. Use AsyncTask - much easier, object oriented that using threads but only for shortlived tasks (under 30 secs)
2. Use RoboSpice - https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice 
   Of the two, I prefer RoboSpice